# Möbius Inversion with Additional Term

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, mobius-inversion

Suppose I have two arithmetic functions $g(n)$ and $f(n)$, where $$g(n) = 1 + \sum_{d|n}f(d). $$ Is it possible to perform a Mobius Inversion and obtain a formula for $f(n)$? If so, how might one proceed? I do not see how to manipulate the above expression to allow a proper inversion to take place.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible for both $f$ and $g$ to be multiplicative, unless $f=0$ and $g=1$.

Comment: @B.Goddard: Are you saying there do not exist two arithmetic functions for which the above equality holds, or that Möbius Inversion requires two arithmetic, multiplicative functions?

Comment: I read the word "multiplicative" into your question.  So I'm saying that if there's a solution, at least one of the functions isn't multiplicative.

Comment: @B.Goddard: So the following would not work, as both are multiplicative functions. Let $\Gamma$ be a quasi-perfect number. From Gauss, we know $\Gamma = \sum_{d|\Gamma}\varphi(d). $ Then, $\sigma(\Gamma) =1+ 2\sum_{d|\Gamma}\varphi(d).$ Can you elaborate on why at least one of the functions isn't multiplicative?

Comment: There should be a question mark at the end of my first sentence above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can apply Möbius inversion if we rewrite the relation

$$g(n) = 1 + \sum_{d \mid n} f(d) \tag{1}$$

by modifying $f$ or $g$. We can look at $\tilde{g} \colon n \mapsto g(n) - 1$, so that $(1)$ becomes

$$\tilde{g}(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} f(d), \tag{$1'$}$$

and apply Möbius inversion. In the resulting sum, we can separate the part arising from $g$ and the part arising from the constant $1$ (which simplifies greatly). The same result is obtained - in a very slightly easier manner - if we modify $f$ rather than $g$ and write $(1)$ as

$$g(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} \tilde{f}(d), \tag{$1''$}$$

where $\tilde{f}(n) = f(n) + e(n)$ with

$$e(n) = \begin{cases} 1 &, n = 1 \\ 0 &, n \neq 1\end{cases}.$$

Möbius inversion gives

$$\tilde{f}(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d) g\biggl(\frac{n}{d}\biggr),$$

which becomes

$$f(n) = \Biggl(\sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d) g\biggl(\frac{n}{d}\biggr)\Biggr) - e(n).$$

Naturally, since $(1)$ involves a term not coming from $f$, the formula for $f(n)$ in terms of $\mu \ast g$ involves a term not coming from $g$. In this case, the extra terms are very simple.

In the comments, the question of multiplicativity was raised. Since $(1)$ in particular yields $g(1) = 1 + f(1)$, and for a nonzero [whether the zero function is considered multiplicative depends on the author] multiplicative function $h$ one has $h(1) = 1$, not both of $f$ and $g$ can be nonzero multiplicative functions: if $f$ is a nonzero multiplicative function, then $g(1) = 2$, so $g$ cannot be multiplicative, and if $g$ is a nonzero multiplicative function, then $f(1) = 0$, so $f$ cannot be a nonzero multiplicative function.

Comment: Funny that you answered this today, I was thinking about this yesterday! I do have a follow up question: will the above hold for $n\in S\subset\mathbb{Z}$ where $S$ is the set of perfect numbers? Or are möbius inversions only applicable provided $n\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you thinking about functions whose domain is $S$, and want something like a Möbius inversion for those functions? I don't see how one could do that, since Möbius inversion uses the multiplicative structure of the positive integers. You have analogues/variants of Möbius inversion on subsets of the positive integers that are closed under multiplication, but the set of perfect numbers isn't closed under multiplication (every proper multiple of a perfect number is abundant). So while we can do it for some proper subsets of the positive integers,

Comment: as far as I can see the set of perfect numbers doesn't have a structure that allows such a theory. But I'm by no means an expert in the field, so it could be that it's possible and I just don't know how.

Comment: I was asking if Möbius inversion (in the traditional sense) was allowed for a restricted domain of $n$. Perhaps perfect numbers was a poor example. Nonetheless, I think you've answered my question. Can you provide an example of a variant of Möbius inversion for a subset of the positive integers that are closed under multiplication?

Comment: If you take a set $P$ of primes, and consider the set $N_P$ of positive integers all of whose prime factors belong to $P$, then we have the Möbius inversion formula for functions $f, g \colon N_P \to \mathbb{C}$, using the restriction of the classical Möbius function $\mu$ to $N_P$. That follows immediately from classical Möbius inversion, since every divisor of $n\in N_P$ also belongs to $N_P$. A variant of that is if we let $P$ consist of powers of different primes, and let $N_P$ be the smallest multiplicatively closed set containing $P$ (and $1$). That uses a different Möbius function,

Comment: $\mu_P(n) = (-1)^r$ if $n$ is the product of $r$ distinct elements of $P$, and $\mu_P(n) = 0$ if in the factorisation of $n$ some element of $P$ appears with an exponent $\geqslant 2$. This variant is however isomorphic to the first version by replacing every $p^a$ in the factorisation of a number with $p$ if $p^a \in P$. So actually these examples are kind of trivial. But I don't know any truly nontrivial examples, though per the general theory of [incidence algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra), one can make things rather general.